# Convert Windows Phone 8 Beta to Public?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I developed some apps for Windows Phone (conversion from other plattforms) and when I finally wanted to upload the apps, I saw this BETA-Feature. You can upload your app and test it in real environment. Sound Great.

Now I have seen all the bugs in this process:

First of all, it seems I cannot convert this app if it is working properly to published app?

I have to crate a new app and I have to re-Enter all the descriptions in all languages and re-upload all screenshots?

Next big problem: I cannot re-use the app name? WTF? My app names are now reserved for these BETA-Apps?

What can I do? I want to convert the apps from BETA to PUBLISHED? Not possible? I have to RE-ENTER ALL INFORMATION IN ALL LANGUAGES? I have to re-upload EVERY Screenshot for EVERY language? I have to use a different name? Is this really the only possibility?

Comment: S***, I have to re-enter all keywords for all languages, re-upload XAP, edit XAP manually before because PubCenter SDK is buggy, ...

Answer (score 0):

On [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215598(v=vs.105).aspx) you can find the description of the beta testing. So, the answer is yes, you need to reinput all data for the production version. In order to use application name in the production release, you can unpublish and delete your beta app. Then you can use its name.

In my own experience, I didn't add much information for the beta distribution. Also, I added suffix *BETA* to the app, which is in beta distribution. So beta testers can recognize the build.